# Transform JavaPairRDD by manipulating its values (Sum) Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Working with apache spark using Java. I got an JavaPairRDD RDD1 and I want to create another JavaPairRdd RDD2 by making the sum of the values of RDD1. However, when I execute the following code,  it blocks in the test_3 transformation without any error message. I think it is related to the issue of performing a rdd transformation or action inside another transformation.

```
JavaPairRDD<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>> test_2 = test_1.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>>, Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>> call(Tuple2<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>> t) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2(t._1,t._2.reduceByKey((Double val1, Double val2)
                    -> Math.pow(Math.abs(val1 - val2), 2)));
        }
    });
   JavaPairRDD<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>> test_3 = test_2.mapToPair
    (new PairFunction<Tuple2<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>>, Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>> call(Tuple2<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>> t)
                throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2(t._1,t._2.values().reduce((Double t1, Double t2) -> t1+t2));
    }});
    JavaPairRDD<Key, Double> test_4= test_3.mapToPair
    (new PairFunction<Tuple2<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>>, Key, Double>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Key, Double> call(Tuple2<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>> t) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple2(t._1,t._2.values().first());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts way before `test_3`. You can not have the value as an RDD. `JavaPairRDD<Key, JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>>` You can probably try to return a list of tuple2(Integer, Double). Something like this: `JavaPairRDD<Key, List<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>>`

Comment: In fact, we can have the value as an RDD. If you can see, when i perfom a collect action on the test_2 RDD, i get the result without problems. In contrast, the issue here is related to the invokation of the values operation in order to sum them. In other words, i need to create a new javaPairRDD having as value the sum of the values of the previous JavaPairRDD (test_2---->test_3).

Comment: It doesn't quite make sense to me how you can have RDD within RDD, I have never seen this use case before. When you do a collect on your `test_2`, if you print out the result, what do you get? Each key has a list of tuple2?

Comment: To response you, if I perform a collect on test_2, I get as result JavaPairRDD with the same key and the value calculated using the formule below; now I need to do the same thing using test_2 by calculating the sum of the values of the pairRDD, however it blocks because i call an action within an RDD transformation.